# correct way to load JS library for custom module

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to use d3.js in my module, but I am facing some issues.

I have the D3 module installed in sites/all/modules/d3/ and d3.min.js installed in sites/all/libraries/d3/, and I can see the d3/examples fine.

Now I have a js script in my custom module that is supposed to use D3, but I fail to load it. Here's my attempt to load the library:

```
drupal_add_library('d3','d3');
# retrieve some data as JSON
$setting = mymodule_load_data($param);
# create the render array
$content = array(
  '#attached' => array(
    # attach JS
    'js' => array(
      array(
        'type' => 'setting',
        'data' => array('mymodule' => array('json_data' => $setting)),
      ),
      array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/js/myscript.js',
      ),
    ),
    'css' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/mystyle.css',
    ),
  )
);
# return result
return $content;
```

but I don't see d3 included in the source code of my page and myscript.js of course doesn't work.

I have checked the return value of drupal_add_library as suggested in the comments and it's FALSE.

Any hints?

Comment: `drupal_add_library` returns a value. The library array, or `FALSE` if the library wasn't found. Check the return value and post an update.

Comment: such value is FALSE

Comment: You could implement [`hook_library_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_library_alter/7.x) in your module. The second argument `$module` can be checked if it matches `d3`, if so, dump the `$libraries` (first argument) to see what libraries this module declares (`dpm()` if you have devel or just `var_dump()`). That might give you a clue on where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`drupal_add_library()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7.x) works only with libraries defined from [`hook_library()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_library/7.x) implementations. Since the [d3.js](https://www.drupal.org/project/d3) module implements hooks used from the [*Libraries API*](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module, you need to use the functions this module make available.

See [Using Libraries API 2.x (as a module-developer)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/libraries-api-7x/using-libraries-api-2x-as-a-module-developer) or [Using Libraries API 1.x (as a module-developer)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/libraries-api/using-libraries-api-1x-as-a-module-developer), basing on which version of the *Libraries API* module you are using.

Normally, with the 2.x branch of the *Libraries API* module, you just call `libraries_load('d3')` which will call `drupal_add_js()`, or `drupal_add_css()`, or both, depending on what the library contains. Otherwise, if you need to check when a library has not been loaded, you use code similar to the following one.

```
if (($library = libraries_load($name)) && !empty($library['loaded'])) {
  // The library has been loaded.
}
```

Even better, using a render array, you just need to use code similar to the following one, which is for the case the library needs to be attached to a form element.

```
$form['myelement']['#attached']['libraries_load'][] = array('d3');
```

For an `hook_page_build()` implementation, adding the library at the page bottom requires code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_page_build(&$page) {
    $page['page_bottom']['d3_library']['#attached']['libraries_load'][] = array('d3');
  }
}
```